# What regex can match sequences of the same character?

Tags: regex, perl

A friend asked me this and I was stumped: Is there a way to craft a regular expression that matches a sequence of the same character? E.g.,  match on 'aaa', 'bbb', but not 'abc'?

```
m|\w{2,3}|
```

Wouldn't do the trick as it would match 'abc'.

```
m|a{2,3}|
```

Wouldn't do the trick as it wouldn't match 'bbb', 'ccc', etc.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Sure thing! Grouping and references are your friends:

```
(.)\1+
```

Will match 2 or more occurences of the same character.  For word constituent characters only, use `\w` instead of `.`, i.e.:

```
(\w)\1+
```

Comment: This will only match some chars, and miss ones like '###'.  The examples he gave where alphabetic chars, but it doesn't really ask for only alphabetic ones.  I'd replace '\w' with '.'.

Comment: Well, based on the non-operational examples the questioner gave, I assumed s/he wanted to match alphabetic characters only. I should have expressed this in the explanation though.

Comment: What does the slash 1 mean?

Comment: \1 is the reference to the first group. (.) is the first group.

Comment: I'm still confused.  So what does \1+ mean? One or more of the first group?  What if the first group (first character) is not followed by the same character?

Comment: how can it be updated to match 1 or more occurrences of the same character?

Comment: @bermick: use `*` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 9):

Note that in Perl 5.10 we have alternative notations for backreferences as well.

```
foreach (qw(aaa bbb abc)) {
  say;
  say ' original' if /(\w)\1+/;
  say ' new way'  if /(\w)\g{1}+/;
  say ' relative' if /(\w)\g{-1}+/;
  say ' named'    if /(?'char'\w)\g{char}+/;
  say ' named'    if /(?<char>\w)\k<char>+/;
}
```

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html or http://perldoc.perl.org/search.html?q=perlre

Answer (score 4):

This will match more than **\w** would, like @@@:

```
/(.)\1+/
```

Comment: This is the right one, for "a sequence of the same character", and not just the "aaa", "bbb" examples. +1

Comment: What is the difference between embedding the expression within slashes "/" and not using them?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question, but got it:

```
m|(\w)\1+|
```

Comment: \W is the opposite of what you want, isn't it?

Comment: Telemachus is right, this will not match the examples you gave in the question.

Comment: Also it is better not to use pipes (or any other non default  delimiters) for the regular expression unless you have a reason to.

Answer (score 1):

This is what backreferences are for.

```
m/(\w)\1\1/
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible using pure regular expressions (i.e. those that describe regular languages -- *not* Perl regexps).  Unfortunately, it means a regexp whose length is proportional to the size of the alphabet, e.g.:

```
(a* + b* + ... + z*)
```

Where a...z are the symbols in the finite alphabet.

So Perl regexps, although a superset of pure regular expressions, definitely have their advantages even when you just want to use them for pure regular expressions!

Answer (score 1):

For same 3 characters:

- `/(.)/1/1/`
- `/(.)/1{2}/`

For 2 characters:

- `/(.)/1/`

For unknown number of same characters:

- `/(.)/1*/`

PS: I use javascript

Comment: It should be `\1` with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

```
".*(.)\\1{2,}.*"
```

Works for any two or more repeated symbols in the string

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Java, and find duplicate chars in given string here is the code,

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "abbc";
    if (s.matches(".*([a-zA-Z])\\1+.*")) {
        System.out.println("Duplicate found!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Duplicate not found!");
    }
}
```

}