# Multiple occurences of same character in a string regexp - Python

Tags: python, regex

Given a string made up of 3 capital letters, 1 small caps and another 3 capital ones,
e.g. AAAaAAA

I can't seem to find a regexp that would find a string which matches a string that has:

- first 3 capital letters all different
- any small caps letter
- first 2 same capital letters as the very first one
- last capital letter the same as the last capital letter in the first "trio"

e.g. **A** B *C* a **AA** *C* (no spaces)

EDIT:

Turns out I needed something slightly different e.g. ABCaAAC where 'a' is the
small caps version of the very fist character, not just any character

Comment: Do you absolutely need this to be a regex? The solution would be way simpler in plain code.

Comment: Not particularly, I just thought regexes where "simpler" than writing loops, if statements and everything else.
Plus I like regexes :)

Comment: Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/644724/2779181). In python, that is `([a-zA-Z])\1{n,}` which means match the same character more than `n+1` times

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following should work:

```
^([A-Z])(?!.?\1)([A-Z])(?!\2)([A-Z])[a-z]\1\1\3$
```

For example:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'^([A-Z])(?!.?\1)([A-Z])(?!\2)([A-Z])[a-z]\1\1\3$')
>>> regex.match('ABAaAAA')  # fails: first three are not different
>>> regex.match('ABCaABC')  # fails: first two of second three are not first char
>>> regex.match('ABCaAAB')  # fails: last char is not last of first three
>>> regex.match('ABCaAAC')  # matches!
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fe09a44a880>
```

Explanation:

```
^          # start of string
([A-Z])    # match any uppercase character, place in \1
(?!.?\1)   # fail if either of the next two characters are the previous character
([A-Z])    # match any uppercase character, place in \2
(?!\2)     # fail if next character is same as the previous character
([A-Z])    # match any uppercase character, place in \3
[a-z]      # match any lowercase character
\1         # match capture group 1
\1         # match capture group 1
\3         # match capture group 3
$          # end of string
```

If you want to pull these matches out from a larger chunk of text, just get rid of the `^` and `$` and use `regex.search()` or `regex.findall()`.

You may however find the following approach easier to understand, it uses regex for the basic validation but then uses normal string operations to test all of the extra requirements:

```
def validate(s):
    return (re.match(r'^[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}$', s) and s[4] == s[0] and 
            s[5] == s[0] and s[-1] == s[2] and len(set(s[:3])) == 3)

>>> validate('ABAaAAA')
False
>>> validate('ABCaABC')
False
>>> validate('ABCaAAB')
False
>>> validate('ABCaAAC')
True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation. Nice to know I was onto something as I was using something similar.
Didn't know about the ?!.? notation.

Comment: @RupertCobbe-Warburton - Just to make sure you are understanding the `(?!.?\1)` portion correctly, `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead, so the match will fail if whatever `...` is can match.  `.?\1` is what we want to fail on, which means optionally match any one character (`.?`), followed by whatever is in the first capture group (`\1`).