# Confused on a basic operation of regular expressions

Tags: regex, dfa, nfa

I have a rather basic question about regexes.
I use the expression `.*` without thinking about it match expecting to match e.g. up to the end of the line. This works.
But for some reason I started thinking about this expression. Checking [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (my emphasis)

```
.  Matches any single character  
*  Matches the **preceding** element zero or more times
```

So now according to this definition, why doesn't `.*` try to match the **first** character in the string 0 or more times but instead tries to apply the match to **each** character in the string?
I mean if I have `abc` it should try to match `a,aa,aaa etc` right?
But it does not:

```
 ~
$ perl -e '  
> my $var="abcdefg";  
> $var =~ /(.*)/;   
> print "$1\n";'   
abcdefg
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's a better answer than: no, because that's not how it's defined.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:The wikipedia definition does not seem to be in contradiction with my assumption (or confusion)

Comment: What I mean is, your assumption about what `.*` should mean does not match the definition.

Answer (score 2):

Confusion starts with the word "element" in `Matches the **preceding** element zero or more times`. Term "preceding element" here refers to "preceding *pattern*" rather than to "preceding *capture*" (or "preceding *match*").

Comment: So the "preceding pattern" is expected to be found 0 or more times. I don't see how this is different with what I am asking

Comment: Different, since you are interpreting "preceding pattern" as "the result of preceding pattern".

Comment: `.*` means "any character 0 or more times" not "optionally find any character that then repeats itself 1 or more times". Consult backreferencing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644714/what-regex-can-match-sequences-of-the-same-character and difference may become clearer.

Comment: Also consult greedy vs. non-greedy matching to understand when `*` operator decides to stop capturing.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
.{2,4}
```

is really shorthand for this:

```
(..)|(...)|(....)
```

In the same way, this:

```
.*
```

is really shorthand for this:

```
()|(.)|(..)|(...)| // etc.
```

Comment: Yes but this is not addressing on why these are equivalent according to how the metacharacter `.` is defined

Comment: @Jim: What "why" are you looking for, exactly?  The above equivalences hold for any character class, whether it's `a`, `[0-9]` or `.`.

Comment: Isn't `x*` the same as `x?x?x?x?x?...`? If yes then why doesn't the `.*` get translated to trying to match the same element That is what is confusing to me

Comment: @Jim: That's another interpretation, yes.  So `.*` would be `.?.?.?...`.  Each `.` is independent of the others.

Answer (score 2):

The . regular expression doesn't have a memory. Once it matched the "a" in "abc" it  forgets about it when trying to match the "b".

Answer (score 1):

`*` applies to the preceding element of the *regular expression* zero or more times - notice the page you link refers to a "pattern element". Therefore when attempting a match at the start of the string, it matches any single character; then it matches any single character, etc.

Similarly if you say `(A|B)*`, it doesn't pick one of `A` or `B` then match it repeatedly; it picks one of `A` or `B` then "starts over".

Answer (score 1):

The `.` means *any single character*, as per the paste from Wikipedia. That doesn't mean the first character only, but really, as it says there, **any** character - that is, any type of character (as opposed to, say, numbers, or white space-type character). So you are saying, match 0 or more occurrences of `any type of character at all`, which of course matches your whole line.

Answer (score 1):

The character dot `.` matches any element

Now the character `*` matches the preceding element (which is any element in our case) 0 or more times.

By:

> the **preceding** element zero or more times

element means `.` and not the preceding character match. It has nothing to do with previous matches. It only repeats the dot 0 or more times.

It's like writing `.?.?` and infinite number of time.