# Cleaning up a regular expression which has lots of repetition

Tags: regex

I am looking to clean up a regular expression which matches 2 or more characters at a time in a sequence. I have made one which works, but I was looking for something shorter, if possible.

Currently, it looks like this for every character that I want to search for:

```
([A]{2,}|[B]{2,}|[C]{2,}|[D]{2,}|[E]{2,}|...)*
```

Example input:

```
AABBBBBBCCCCAAAAAADD
```

Comment: Unclear for me. Explain your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644714/what-regex-can-match-sequences-of-the-same-character), which I think was asking the same thing you are asking. You want to write a regex that will match 2 or more of the same character. Let's say the characters you are looking for are just capital letters, `[A-Z]`. You can do this by matching one character in that set and grouping it by putting it in parentheses, then matching that group using the reference `\1` and saying you want two or more of that "group" (which is really just the one character that it matched).

```
([A-Z])\1{1,}
```

The reason it's `{1,}` and not `{2,}` is that the first character was already matched by the set `[A-Z]`.

Comment: i think it would be `([A-Z])\1{1,}`

Comment: Wouldn't that be *one* or more characters?

Comment: This works great, thanks! Avinash's correction is what I will use, but I'm not sure why it works better.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your needs but, how about:

```
[A-E]{2,}
```

This is the same as yours but shorter.

But if you want multiple occurrences of each letter:

```
(?:([A-Z])\1+)+
```

where `([A-Z])` matches one capital letter and store it in group 1
`\1` is a backreference that repeats group 1
`+` assume that are one or more repetition
Finally it matches strings like the one you've given: `AABBBBBBCCCCAAAAAADD`

To be sure there're no other characters in the string, you have to anchor the regex:

```
^(?:([A-Z])\1+)+$
```

And, if you wnat to match case insensitive:

```
^(?i)(?:([A-Z])\1+)+$
```

Comment: It's a good attempt, my question was not worded particularly well.