# Regular Expressions - Grouping Similar Characters

Tags: regex, grouping

Can someone give me a regular expression to group a string by the identical characters?

Example:

```
For "111222333" ---> "111", "222", "333"
For "122111"    ---> "1", "22", "111"
For "121"       ---> "1", "2", "1"
```

Comment: What language, tool?

Comment: This seems to be answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644714/what-regex-can-match-sequences-of-the-same-character

Comment: Actually, the `(.)\1*` is the one you need here. Just grab the capture group #1 values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
(.)\1*
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://regexr.com/3f8k0)