# Regex: quantifying the same character

Tags: regex, quantifiers

How can I match the repetition of a character n times?

For example with this sample text

> abc**ddd**d123
>
> 123456**777**xssx

I want to match the three consecutive 7 and the three consecutive d

I've tried with

```
.{3}
```

But the quantifier {3}, as well as other quantifiers such as the asterisk, dones't seem to quantify the same character but any other different character as well.
I mean it doesn't repeat the first matched character muy the dot itself.
In my example it will match everything.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644714/what-regex-can-match-sequences-of-the-same-character

Comment: `(.)\1{2}` = capture anything then use a backreference to it 2 more times. Result = same character 3 in a sequence. Some want quick eye recognition on the quantifier. For them, it would be `(?=(.))\1{3}`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a group you can probably end up doing something like this to match any consecutive letter or number 3 times

```
([a-Z1-9])\1\1\1
```