# python regular expression not matching properly

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

`"aaabbbbccc"`

I want to retrieve 
`["aaa", "bbbb", "ccc"]`

According to this post
[What regex can match sequences of the same character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644714/what-regex-can-match-sequences-of-the-same-character)

```
In [8]: re.findall('(\w)\1+', s)
Out[8]: []
```

I think I successfully retrieved this pattern using a online regex parser.

Comment: Not regex but you could also use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby): `[''.join(x) for _,x in itertools.groupby("aaabbbbccc")]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things you should consider here:

1) Use raw string literals when defining regex (or double escape the `\` inside the pattern so that `\1` could be parsed as a backreference and not as an octal character notation), and

2) Use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) here to get *whole match values* since [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) will fetch only the values *captured* with capturing groups:

```
import re
s = 'aaabbbbccc'
print([x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'(\w)\1+', s)])
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/YXPf06).

Here, `x.group()` is the whole match stored inside the `re.MatchObject` that is returned by `re.finditer`.