# Matching two strings together with Substituted Characters

Tags: c#

Imagine a gamble game where you have to match all three words to get a reward.

So if you get `HHH` you get an award.

I want to be able to subsitute `W` to mimick any letter.

For example:

```
HWW = HHH
```

and

```
HHW = HHH
```

but

```
WWW = WWW
```

How do i go about doing this?

Comment: Your composition is not really technical. So if I undetsand well, you are trying somehing like pattern matching and W is a joker character or so called wild-card?

Comment: So basically if any of the 3 letters is an **H** then the output will be **HHH** else **WWW** So just do a `"HWW".Constains("H")` If this is not what you want, then we need more examples. be more precise

Comment: @koviroli thats correct

Comment: My question would be is how i get W to play the joker and be applied to any pattern.

Comment: Could do it with a regex like `(\w|W)(\1|W)(\1|W)` https://regex101.com/r/IcMWPE/1 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644714/what-regex-can-match-sequences-of-the-same-character

Comment: @AndreasHassing how would i put that into an if statement? i looked around but its very confusing. Say i had a string of 3 characters, and i wanted to check if it Equals HHH or WWW.

Comment: Disregard my comment @Prime, it does not cover the scenario where the first character is a wildcard character :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before matching a string to a pattern, change the **wild card** characters to a character that matches to anything. Like this:

```
  // this method change W wild-card character to a character that match anything
  private static bool MatchToString(string stringToMatch, string pattern) {
      Regex r = new Regex(pattern.Replace("W", "."));
      return r.Match(stringToMatch).Success;
  }
  static void Main() {
  // these are matches
  Console.WriteLine(MatchToString("HHH", "HWW"));
  Console.WriteLine(MatchToString("HHH", "HHW"));
  Console.WriteLine(MatchToString("WWW", "WWW"));
  Console.WriteLine(MatchToString("HHWH", "WWWW"));

  //these are doesn't
  Console.WriteLine(MatchToString("HHH", "HHK"));
  Console.WriteLine(MatchToString("HHH", "HKK"));
  Console.WriteLine(MatchToString("WWW", "ABC"));

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```