# How to detect if 2 or more symbols are next to each other in a python string and replace them with one

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to detect if there are 2 or more symbols like + or = or - are next to each other in a python string because I am getting the data from a tkinker entry and it can replace the multiple symbols with only one ? For example if the user enters 3 +++ 3 and it will only process it with one + like 3 + 3? I have tried `(.)\1` but it only works for pairs. Which you can try [here](https://regexr.com/3h0g0)
Help would be appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close to the solution ! You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645085/7002298) to support more than pairs:

```sh
# \1+ means: "one or more repetition of the text matched by the first group"
# so this results in 2+ repetition of the same letter here
(.)\1+
```

Of course, you can then narrow down the duplicated characters you want to detect by changing the `.` to `[=+-]` for example.

Here is the regex with some unit tests: https://regex101.com/r/KhUoyy/1