# remove multiple occurred chars from a string except one char in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

If a dataframe is looks like this `df = df.withColumn('NUM_COL', lit('Hey$$$ Hey$ T$$'))` and when I need to make this string as
`Hey$ Hey$ T$`. I couldn't find any proper solutions for this. For an instance in IBM datastage there is a way to do this by using `Trim(mylink.mystring,".")` for remove redundant chars. What would be the best solution for this in PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[regexp_replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html) should do the job:

```python
df = df.withColumn('replaced', F.regexp_replace('value', r'(.)\1+', '$1'))
```

The idea is here to use the (first) group from the [pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/644724/2129801) as replacement.